# Mensagem ao usuário com tempo e redirecionamento de página matando sessão

Tags: php

Estou tentando fazer um redirecionamento após dar uma mensagem ao usuário, mas a mensagem não está sendo exibida e muito menos a sessão sendo destruída, não sei exatamente o que está errado, o código que tenho até agora é esse:

```
// SEGURANÇA DE ACESSO 
$sqlUsuario = "SELECT * FROM cadUsuario WHERE IdUsuario = ? AND IdPessoa = ?";
$stm = $conexao->prepare($sqlUsuario);
// DEFINE O TIPO DA VARIÁVEL INT OU STR
$stm->bindValue(1, $IdUsuario, PDO::PARAM_INT); 
$stm->bindValue(2, $IdPessoa, PDO::PARAM_INT);  
$stm->execute();    
$sqlUsuario = $stm->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ); 
// CONTAGEM DE REGISTROS RETORNADOS
$contUsuarios = count($sqlUsuario); 
// FECHANDO A CONSULTA
$stm->closeCursor(); 

//SE EXISTIR USUÁRIO MOSTRA CONTEÚDO
if ($contUsuarios > 0) {

// CÓDIGO DA PÁGINA

} else {

// SE NÃO EXISTIR USUÁRIO EXIBIR MENSAGEM

    echo "Erro e redireciona ";    
    sleep(10);  

    // DESTRUINDO A SESSÃO
    session_start();
    session_unset();
    session_destroy();
    session_write_close();
    setcookie(session_name(),'',0,'/');
    session_regenerate_id(true); 
    header("Location:index.php");

}
```

A mensagem está estilizada dessa forma:

```html
echo "<div align='center' class='alert alert-danger'>Erro e redireciona </div>";
```

Comment: de onde vem esse $contUsuarios ?

Comment: Olá @VME, inseri o código na pergunta.

Comment: Tente alterar $contUsuarios = count($sqlUsuario);  para $contUsuarios = $stm->rowCount(); e veja se resulta algo. Se não, dê um echo $contUsuarios para ver qual a saída

Comment: Se houver erros, não está nesse código da pergunta.

Comment: A `fetchAll` pode retornar `false`. E se você fizer um `count(false)` o resultado será 1. E no php 5 não gera warning. Então, o melhor seria usar a sugestão do @VME